# Unable to login with Instabot : Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api, instapy

**This is my simple code**

```
from instabot import Bot
import os
import glob

cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*.txt")
os.remove(cookie_del[0])
cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*.json")
os.remove(cookie_del[0])

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="myusername", password="mypassword")

######  upload a picture #######
bot.upload_photo("/home/2.jpeg", caption="biscuit eating baby")
```

**ERRORS**

```
2022-04-11 19:00:17,124 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2022-04-11 19:00:17,125 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2022-04-11 19:00:17,882 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2022-04-11 19:00:17,882 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
```

I was finding the solutions on stack overflow, I searched almost half of the internet:

While trying to many solutions it worked once but only once got some image dimensions error that time:

> 1. I tried instagram official API but stuck in review application

> 2. I tired with selenium but stuck because unable to select file automatically

> 3. I tried other instagram packages and github still got issues

**Please send some code, any reference or alternative solution to automate image uploading process with python**

Comment: I am having the same problem. Tell me how you solve it!

Comment: Im still finding the solution ;;;